# Can i re-use webRTC Peer Connection object for Multi user chat?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection, signaling

I have used `WebRTC` for my chat application. My idea is whenever any user has joined in the chat application then a new `RTCPeerConnection` object will create. The chat room will allow only `one-to-one communication`.

**Example**: Suppose `User1` , `User2` and `User3` has joined application. If `user1` want to chat with `user2` then a Room will be created between those users.

Here `user1` has `RTCPeerConnection` and `user2` has it's own `RTCPeerConnection`. Next `webRTC negotiation` (exchange offer, answer and ICE) will happen between them via signaling. Data can be shared through RTC Data channel.

If `user1` want to connect with `user3`, then `user1` has to leave the previous room and do the webRTC negotiation with `user3` (means previous room delete and new room has to create).

**Now my question is**:

Suppose `user1` and `user2` is doing webRTC communication then

**user 1**  `RTCPeerConnection.signalingstatechange = have-local-offer`

**user 2**   `RTCPeerConnection.signalingstatechange = have-remote-offer`

After that i have closed the connection (means room deleted). Next `user1` want to connect with `user3`.

In this case, can i re-use the User1's `RTCPeerConnection` to create the new offer for `user3` ?

If Yes, What are the things i have to taken care during the deletion of a previous connection ? because the previous `signalingstatechange` is `have-local-offer` and `have-remote-offer`. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: use peerjs , you just have to send each peer.id for other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't re-use a PeerConnection like that. If you want to create a mesh connection between the three users it will look like.

```
user-1 <--> user-2
  ^              ^
  |              |
  ---> user-3 <--
```

Each user will create two PeerConnections to have P2P connections with the other users.